# How to add dynamic field types to Angular FormArray?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build a block editor type form in Angular. I want this form to be just one array of dynamic fields. I have the following code so far but the button to add different fields always adds all fields instead of the one it should. How can I add only that specific field to the array? What is the best approach to develop this kind of form?

**Form TS**

```
storyForm = this.story.group({
    blocks: this.story.array([]),
});

get blocks() {
    return this.storyForm.get('blocks') as FormArray;
}
```

**Buttons to add different fields to the above array**

```
addHeading() {
    this.blocks.push(this.story.group({
      heading: [''],
    }));
}  

addParagraph() {
    this.blocks.push(this.story.group({
      paragraph: [''],
    }));
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="form-group" formArrayName="blocks">
    <div *ngFor="let piece of blocks.controls; let i=index">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="heading" formControlName="heading" ></textarea>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="paragraph" formControlName="paragraph" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="addParagraph()">Add Paragraph</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="addHeading()">Add Heading</button>
```

Comment: This can help you:
https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe

Comment: @JuanPabloMorenoMartín In this tutorial, you can add the same set of fields to the array. I want to add different fields and maintain the order of these fields.